# problem of sending/receive data from vuejs to SpringBoot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to send data from Vuejs to SpringBoot with HTTP method
In my vuejs application:

```
let message = encodeURIComponent(this.NonFichier)
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:8080/apii/Recevoir', message)
    .then((resonse) => {
      console.log(resonse.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
},
```

and in my SpringBoot programme :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/Recevoir", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> recevoir(@RequestBody String message) {
    System.out.println("Le message reçu est : " + message);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("String reçu avec succès ! et la donner recu est : " + message);
}
```

But the problem is I do not receiv the same data
For exemple if i send =

> file14/04/2023

In spring I receive :

> file14%2F04%2F2023=

Please, what i can do to receive the same data that i send ?

Comment: How did you get encodeURIComponent("file14/04/2023")="file14%2F04%2F2023=" instead of encodeURIComponent("file14/04/2023")='file14%2F04%2F2023'?

You have to decode the message in backend to receive the wanted (encoded) message.

Comment: even without encoding it doesn't work